# Inline alias for Kotlin function that includes generics?

Tags: generics, properties, kotlin, inline

I have shortened the names of some frequently-used foreign functions (that I don't control) with "aliases", based on advice I received in [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631293/kotlin-extension-method-as-alias-for-long-method-name).  This has worked nicely for extension functions; however, I have a few top-level functions I'd like to alias as well.  For a simplified example, consider the `generateSequence` function.  I want to be able to do this:

```
// DOES NOT COMPILE
inline val <T:Any> seq:(()->T?)->Sequence<T> get() = ::generateSequence
```

...but I can't because the generic must be used in the receiver type, as explained well [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181945/kotlin-property-type-parameter-of-a-property-must-be-used-in-its-receiver-type).  Is there any other way to create an **alias for a top-level function (requiring generics) which preserves the inline?**

**EDIT:** I tried using `Any?` and star projection right after posting the question, but I still don't think it's a good answer:

```
inline val seq:(()->Any?)->Sequence<*> get() = ::generateSequence
```

This seems boptimalsu because it compromises type-checking on the Sequence's element type, correct?  Other answers/thoughts as to what could work?

Answer (score 2):

An option that you could use is a renaming import, though it is limited to a single source file:

```
import kotlin.sequences.generateSequence as seq

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    seq(1) { it + 1 }.take(10).forEach(::println)
}
```

Apart from that, I think, the best you could do is to fall back to declaring another inline function:

```
inline fun <T> seq(nextFunction: () -> T?) = 
    generateSequence(nextFunction)
```

In fact, I'd expect the performance of this option to be better than of the one with a function reference, because using an inline property returning a function reference still has some overhead when you make a call to that reference, while this call is inlined and thus should introduce no overhead for another nested call.

Comment: I like your inline function approach, but I thought that returns an `illegal use of inline-parameter` error.  I used the inline property because I couldn't find another way to do it inline, even after asking [this question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605151).  Do you think the inline property (function reference) would perform worse than a function with a `noinline` lambda parameter (assuming I'm talking about a function where I can do it -- i.e., that doesn't require generics)?